# android maps api v2 adding multiple circles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to add a circle to the map every second with an update from the gps. How would I pass the Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); to make a new circle every second? Here is what I have so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

Location myLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);





Location myLocation;

LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, (LocationListener) this);

CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
.center(new LatLng( , ))
.radius(3.048); // In meters

Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);



 }
```

}

Comment: Checkout this library: https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `getLastKnownLocation`, you are better of using `LocationListener`'s callback: `onLocationChange` for that, which you seem to implement and request already.

To convert `Location` to `LatLng` use:

```
new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())
```

Comment: It seems to add a new circle with present location, but I want it to keep the old circles too so that I can see what path I have taken (similar to a highlighted route on a gps). What do I add to have it keep adding new circles? Thanks.

Comment: @user1936916 Circles are added when you call `mMap.addCircle`. Just don't call `mMap.clear` or `circle.remove`.