# Android maps api v2 Circles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

Not sure what is going on here, but I want it to make an additional circle every second as the device moves. All it does is make 1 circle. I want the circles to highlight the route I have taken. Recommendations? Thanks

```
LocationManager locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria cr = new Criteria();
String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, (LocationListener) this);




CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
.center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
circleOptions.radius(3.048); // In meters


mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android maps api v2 adding multiple circles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766544/android-maps-api-v2-adding-multiple-circles)

Comment: Didn't figure out how to place modified code back in question.

Comment: checkout this library: https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put:

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
        .center(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
circleOptions.radius(3.048); // In meters

mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

inside [`onLocationChanged(Location location)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) callback.